# How to allocate & resize memory of int*** array?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, malloc, realloc

For a school project we have to make a certain program which requires the use of memory allocation.
I use an `int *** array`, however when I declare the memory for it to use, I cannot get it to function correctly. I imagine this is because at some point I'm calling memory that has not yet been allocated, though I cannot find where.
The array is always of `3*size*unknown size` where the unknown is dynamically allocated as the program runs.

```
arr = (int***)realloc(arr, sizeof(int**) * 3);

for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    arr[n] = (int**)realloc(arr[n], sizeof(int*) * size);
}

for (int n = 1; n < 3; n++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        arr[n][x] = (int*)realloc(arr[n][x], sizeof(int));
        arr[n][x][0] = n - 1;
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is the school project in C or C++?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `malloc()`, not `realloc()` for the first allocation.

Comment: You sure? Realloc() you want to use not malloc()

Comment: @MikeCAT - If `arr` is null then it should be fine

Comment: Why would you use such a complicated thing in a school project? Perhaps you could explain what you want to achieve, we then could perhaps *really* help you.

Comment: you seem to only have one element in the third dimension of the array, so does this suggest that maybe the array should be 2D rather than 3D? Also note that the third set of for loops skips initialising the first section of the array and start from the second

Comment: But when he does realloc() on the array items, they are definitely not initialized beforehand. This must segfault virtually every time.

Comment: This is just too messy to be useful:(

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `malloc` first, then `realloc` in case you want to change the size of the memory.

> The array is always of 3*size*unknown size

First you initially allocate the memory using `malloc`

```
int main (void)
{
    int val = 1;
    int LENGTH = 4;
    const int SIZE = 10;
    int ** arr[3];

    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*SIZE);

        for (int j=0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LENGTH);

            for (int k=0; k < LENGTH; k++)
            {
                arr[i][j][k] = val++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then when you want to resize the memory using `realloc`

```
    val = 1;
    LENGTH = 8;

    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = (int*)malloc(arr[i][j], sizeof(int)*LENGTH);

            for (int k=0; k < LENGTH; k++)
            {
                arr[i][j][k] = val++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can test it by printing the values in the array

```
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("---------- %d ----------\n", i);
        for (int j=0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            for (int k=0; k < LENGTH; k++)
            {
                printf("  %d", arr[i][j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("---------- %d ----------\n\n",i);
    }
```

Then when you are done with the array, you can free the memory using `free`

```
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            free(arr[i][j]);
        }

        free(arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use realloc first, provided it's initialised to null.

Comment: @Flexo yes, `realloc(null,..)` is equivlant to `malloc(..)`, but I think the OP need to learn some basics here

Comment: @Flexo `size` is constant but not necessarily known at compile-time, initialization would be time costly

Answer (score 1):

If only the last dimension is unknown then you can write much simpler code:

```
#define lengthof(array) ( sizeof(array) / sizeof ((array)[0]) )

int *arr[3][size];
```

and then to set them all to a known state:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != lengthof(arr); ++i)
    for (size_t j = 0; j != lengthof(arr[i]); ++j)
         arr[i][j] = 0;
```

and then to change size:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != lengthof(arr); ++i)
    for (size_t j = 0; j != lengthof(arr[i]); ++j)
    {
        void *temp = realloc(arr[i][j], unknown_size * sizeof *arr[i][j])) )
        if ( !temp )
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // or other error handling
        arr[i][j] = temp;
    }
```

NB. Be careful if you put this allocation code into a function.

Comment: `size` is constant but not necessarily known at compile-time, in which case `= { 0 }` will give a compilation error, and `memset(arr, 0, lengthof(arr))` should be used instead

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer thanks for pointing that out. `memset` is non-portable here so I have edited my code.

Answer (score -3):

As your code seems C++ to me:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    int*** arr = new int**[a];

    for (int i = 0;i < a;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int*[b];
        for (int j = 0;j < b;j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = new int[c];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that it is C++ and not C? There is not a single specific C++ construct in the orginal code.

Comment: Please tell me why you think it is c++ when you have `realloc`?

Comment: Because of used c++ tag

Comment: So the C++ tag trumps the C tag?

Comment: The c tag was also used so its unclear which the OP is using.

Comment: And if you what an answer in C++ why is your answer not use `std::vector`?

Comment: @Ed Heal exactly, I think that OP is aware of languages historical and compability order

Comment: @Ed Heal I thought that the question was to allocate memory to array, not to use vector.

Comment: Does a vector allocate memory?

Comment: Yes, dunno what this talk about, OP used c++ tag so isn't my answer acceptable?

Comment: The OP code is using `realloc` - This is C code. Not C++

Comment: @EdHeal `realloc` is usable in C++.  In fact the C++ allocator model does not have any equivalent of realloc so in some cases it is the best option.